# Some of the tasks in the SSIS package failed when I migrated the package to another server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Sorry, I'm new to SSIS development. The title I've given to the problem isn't so appropriate  - please go through below.

I have a SSIS package in the C drive of a local server, which everyone on the team has access to. If I login using my windows username and password, I can execute the "Execute SQL tasks" in the SSIS package, and it completes successfully. The package contains 3 "execute sql task" all of which run OK.

When my teammate tries to execute the package with his username and password
it shows an error, of the 3 "Execute SQL tasks" only 1 executed successfully, the other 2 error out with the following:

> Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC
>   usp_ETL_GetRepairHistoryFacts" failed with the following error: "The
>   statement has been terminated.". Possible failure reasons: Problems
>   with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not
>   set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

What we can't understand is we are using the same SSIS package, same databases, the only difference is the logins.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to resolve this?

Comment: In execute sql task r u accessing different stored procedures?Verify that the users have access to all the stored procedures which are used in execute sql task

Answer (score 3):

Is your SQL Server using authenticated Windows logins? It sounds that way.

If so, I would have your team-mate login to SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), start a New Query and run the "EXEC usp..." statement.

You might see an error message. My guess is that it's a permissions problem with the stored procedure "usp_ETL..." It sounds like you have execute permissions and he/she does not.

Comment: thanx for the reply do you mean something like                 Grant exec on usp_ETL_GetRepairHistorFacts to user2

Comment: by the way what exactly is the difference between user   and     logins?

Comment: when we made a change of default language from british englsih to english on the sql server property.I mean Server property-->General-->Language